# Why my Supertest test that should be failing is passing?

Tags: node.js, express, supertest

I'm starting my project based on this repo:
https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose

The first thing I decided to do was write tests, so I went to the test file, and it looks something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var should = require('should');
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../server');
var context = describe;
// other stuff you want to include for tests

before(function (done) {
  // clear db and other stuff
  done();
});

describe('Users', function () {
  describe('POST /users', function () {
    it('should create a user', function (done) {

      request(app)
      .post('/users')
      .field('name', 'foo')
      .field('email', 'foo')
      .field('password', 'foo')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
        console.log(err);
        if(err){
          console.log("error");
        }
        // console.log(res);
      });


      done();
    });
  });
});

after(function (done) {
  // do some stuff
  done();
});
```

I haven't actually created the route, so the test should be failing, and I even do get an error on .end, so any idea why is the test not failing?

My console shows me this when I run npm test

```
Express app started on port 3000


  Users
    POST /users
      ✓ should create a user
[Error: expected "Content-Type" matching /json/, got "text/html; charset=utf-8"]
error


  1 passing (653ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your test is asynchronous, but your code is synchronous. Specifically, the `done()` line is always called.

You need to move the `done()` line into the `.end` block, and add `done(err)` for the error case, like this:

```
.end(function(err, res){
    if(err){
        console.log("error");
        done(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(res);
        done();
    }
});
```